# Recursively iterate over arrays objects and return array of connected ids

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could you please help me- I have the following list of data:

```
var data = [
        { id:'1', childId: ["2", "3"] },
        { id:"2", childId: ["4"] },
        { id:"3", childId: ["4", "5"] },
        { id:"4", childId: null },
        { id:"5", childId: null }
    ];
```

I want to get an array of connected nodes ids

```
var connections = findConnections('1') //id


id = 1 -->[]

id = 2 -->['1']

id = 3 --> ['1']

id = 4 --> ['3','2']

id = 5 -->['3']
```

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If you want help, you first need to show us what you have tried/attempted and what specific problems you had with that approach(es)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and `childId` and take this values as key for an object with arrays for `id`.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", childId: ["2", "3"] }, { id: "2", childId: ["4"] }, { id: "3", childId: ["4", "5"] }, { id: "4", childId: null }, { id: "5", childId: null }],
    targets = data.reduce((r, { id, childId }) => {
        r[id] = r[id] || [];
        (childId || []).forEach(k => (r[k] = r[k] || []).push(id));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(targets);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and what about this case:

```js
var data = [
  { id: '1', type: 'bananas', yellow: ['2', '3'] },
  { id: '2', type: 'pears', greens: ['4'] },
  { id: '3', type: 'pears', greens: ['4', '5'] },
  { id: '4', type: 'pears', greens: null },
  { id: '5', type: 'pears', greens: null },
];

const MAP_CHILD_ID = {
  bananas: 'yellow',
  pears: 'greens',
};

function getConnections(id) {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.childId && item.childId.includes(id)) {
      acc.push(item.id)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
};

var a = getConnections('1');
```

want to receive an array of all ids nested with this id
 s the result would be ['2','3','4','5']

Comment: Please don't ask another question in an answer.  Instead, open a new question, or if it's a minor modification, edit your question.